Most Widely Held Theories of How "Moral Sense" Arises in a Culture
I am the kind of person who is slow to really "get" some of my fellow citizens moral sense (often codified in rules of thumb in proverbial sayings). I almost prefer the hard way of a discourse to "straightforward" one-liners. I enjoy learning about animals, and how their instincts prepare them for survival. I like the concept of studying an evolutionary history of how a eusocial concept becomes common knowledge in human communities.
Would there be any contemporary philosophers that study not so much the content of moral sense, but how a community forms a distinct moral sense? Or is this generally studied as part of a wider field?


common sense (which I define as ethical rules of thumb)

I am not sure how you come to take the expression "ethical rules of thumb" as a clarification of the expression "common sense". Common sense is certainly not defined as "rules", even less as "ethical rules".
Here is for comparison the definition offered by the Collins dictionary:

common sense: plain ordinary good judgment; sound practical sense

This may not be rigorous but we get the idea. Basically, common sense is the set of ideas which normal humans would normally all acquire from the same experience of reality. It is relative to an experience, and acquiring common sense obviously requires a healthy brain.

how a person or people understand common sense?

We don't "understand" common sense. We acquire it through experience and therefore perception, exactly through the same cognitive process as anyone acquires any given competency on the world through perception.
The notion of common sense goes back at least to Aristotle, who explained that animals rely on tastes, colours, feelings, smells and sounds to think of real things in terms of "common sensibles". The Wikipedia page on "common sense" gives the basic references relevant to the subject.

Soon after the acceptance of the theory of evolution, there have been efforts to derive moral thinking from it.
Perhaps the earliest derivation would be the celebration of predation, violence, and reproductive success, that is exemplified by Jack London's "Law of Tooth and Claw".  London considered violence and killing to be evolutionarily justified, and celebrated success at both.
The Law of Tooth and Claw neglects that most living things are not apex predators, and that there is a lot more to evolutionary success than the size of one's teeth.
Another early effort to make this connection from evolution to morality was Social Darwinism, and SD explicitly attempted to include sociology in its understanding of how to apply evolution to morality.  SD was far more subtle than Jack London, and recognized all sorts of non-violence factors could affect evolutionary success.  The major concern of SD, however, was to rationalize reducing human empathy and our social safety net, out of fear that we were vitiating the robustness of future generations.
The Eusociality you reference is an even more subtle and interesting thesis, as it addresses your question of WHY societies have norms and morality.  Eusociality's answer is basically to support/maintain those temporarily in need within the "us" group, and to establish us/them boundaries vs other human groups.  Hence in-group altruism IS what evolution promotes in humans along with an us/them tribalism -- and the purpose of many societal norms is just to create a rationale for an us/them hostility, not any other real value.
If you want to find more on Eusociality, the best reference is the main promoter of this idea, E. O. Wilson.
Additionally, some other interesting thinking is the Selfish Gene concept by Dawkins, in which our norms and behaviors are often better understood as us being manipulated BY OUR GENES.  Also of even more interest and subtlety is the selfish MEME concept.  Here is a review:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/ROUSR7DAL2NMS/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0521606276  If our minds are partially parasitized by self-interested memes, hen what we do socially may not actually be traceable to anything in either our self-interest, morality, or genetics!
Another useful study in this direction is how we develop our sense of morality.  Here are the six stages of moral development identified by Kohlberg:  https://www.verywellmind.com/kohlbergs-theory-of-moral-development-2795071
With evolution operating in multiple modes (individual dominance, individual effectiveness, community eusociality, serving our genes, serving our memes), there is no straightforward procedure for predicting what norms or conventions any particular society will adopt.  But what those are -- will be influenced by all of the above.
Non-evolutionary theories of how social mores develop tend to presume the existence of an objective morality, which our moral sense is able to detect.  Our moral sense is -- weak, and hijacked to do things like us/them grouping, so our moral intuitions are not entirely trustworthy.
BUT, if one searches for the cross-cultural commonalities of morality, and the cross-cultural approval of moral theories, and the cross-cultural admiration of saintly behavior, THEN one can identify a likely "real" morality through the noise of evolutionary distortions induced in us because evolution uses morality for other purposes than just truth-detection.
